# What will happen if a corner flag blocks the football rolling out of bounds?

Tags: rules, football

What happens when the ball rebounds off the corner flag? Does it count as out of bounds? Or does the match just continue?

Comment: There is an example of it happening here, with the match continuing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jszMeoVWwtE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Play continues as usual. Ball doesnt count as going out of bounds until it actually goes out of bounds. 
FIFA Laws of the game 2015/16, page 34 (emphasis my own):

> *Ball out of play*
>
> The ball is out of play when:
>
> - it has wholly crossed the goal line or touch line whether on the ground or in the air
> - play has been stopped by the referee
>
> *Ball in play*
>
> The ball is in play at all other times, including when:
>
> - it rebounds off a goalpost, crossbar or **corner flagpost** and remains in the field of play
> - it rebounds off either the referee or an assistant referee when they are on the field of play